# Change glyphicon on click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I am trying to change this glyphicon on click but it works fine when href = "#" but originally my href contains a url which through a view hits the database in django.

HTML:

```
<div class='hidden-lg'>

    <div class="content-header">
         <h1>
            <a id = "star" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Add to your list" data-placement="top">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </a>
            </h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#star').click( function(){

$(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star');

});
```

This works fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/asees/5XqyW/564/

But when i change href to the below code, there is no change on glyphicon.

```
<a id = "star" href="{% url 'add' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Add to your list" data-placement="top">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: i dont see `#menu-toggle` in your fiddle.

Comment: @DanielA.White edited the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XqyW/566/)**.

Since you're clicking on anchor `#star` you need to prevent the default event 
 (redirecting to `href`) using `e.preventDefault()` like :

```
$('#star').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star');
});
```

Comment: But this will not hit the url.I want it to hit the url as well so that it can interact with db.